# How to disable Flickable of Gridview/Listview in QML language

Tags: qt, listview, gridview, qml

I met the problem when creating Gridview in QML language. I create a list models and populate them to gridview. When I using scroll mouse strickly to scroll data display in gridview, the data disappear(I don't know why???). I thinks it cause by Flickable in Gridview. 
How can disable Flickable in Gridview?
My snips code:

```html
                Flickable{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    interactive: false
                    GridView{//Grid display book
                        id: mainGrid
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        cellWidth: 130
                        cellHeight: 132
                        //displayMarginBeginning: 5
                        model: bookModel
                        delegate: MyDelegate{}
                    }
                    QBookModel{
                        id: bookModel
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridView` is a sub-type of `Flickable`, so you have to disable [`interactive`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#interactive-prop) property in your `GridView` as well, not just in the parent `Flickable`.

Comment: Thanks for your guide @Jeffrey. It is my answer.